# Python multiprocessing: no output with while-loop in worker function

Tags: python

I'm exploring the Python multiprocessing module and don't understand why the following code does not print anything at all. Without the while-loop the program prints Worker_1 as expected.

```
import multiprocessing, time

def worker1():
    print 'Worker_1'
    while 1:
        print 'Worker_1'
        time.sleep(3)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker1)
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

Comment: I'm not a master on the multiprocessing module, and I cant test it right now, but try adding `p.join()` after your `p.start()`. If the main program exits after the subprocess is started, does the subprocess continue? I don't think so, but I don't know. Note that this means you'll have to do some shenanigans to make the worker stop when you want it to. Alternatively, look at the fork module maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system (Python 2.6&2.7 on Linux), this works as expected. Which platform are you using? On some platforms(Windows), `fork` hast to be emulated by creating a totally new process and setting it up. I suspect some `stdout` is not transferred to the child process. Try:

- The [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module. It's sufficient if you just want to wait for an event in a thread.
- Running your program on a POSIX-compatible platform, such as BSD, Linux or Solaris
- Outputting to a file

Comment: Currently I'm working with Eclipse and PyDev on Windows. Outputting to a file doesn't work either. I just get an empty file. What I don't understand is the significance of the while-loop. There is output without the loop, but no output with it.

Comment: Try adding sys.stdout.flush() maybe?

Comment: I can't believe that `print("something")` doesn't work in a child process on Windows. `fork` is not the reason. I've tried the ported to Python 3.4 code from the question and it produces the expected output with [`multiprocesssing.set_start_method('spawn')`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) ('fork' naturally works too).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IDLE? I think that this is the problem. The code you have works for me in Linux when called from the command line (it prints 'Worker_1' every 3 seconds). When I try it in IDLE, it stops immediately. This is because you don't have the `p.join()` in there which results in the main process stopping right away which then stops the worker process. Apparently, `p.join()` isn't as necessary from the command line in Linux though I would recommend it anyway.

However, even with `p.join()` and using IDLE, the script just sits there and we don't see any text. This is, I think, because of the weird way that IDLE reroutes stdout to idlelib.rpc.RPCProxy. So, in other words, if you are using IDLE, then that is your problem.

Comment: I'm using Ecplise with PyDev on Windows.