# Python; unable to run multiple processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run 2 separate processes in my python application. So I have code like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f1():
  while 1:  
    print('Hello')

def f2():
  while 1:
    print('Goodbye')


def main():
    p1 = Process(target=f1, args=())
    p1.start()
    p1.join()

    p2 = Process(target=f2, args=())
    p2.start()
    p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code does nothing on my machine, it doesn't produce any output. I thought initially that maybe it was an IDE-related problem, but it's the same on both my IDEs, PyScripter and IDLE.
Any ideas, why this doesn't print anything?

Comment: Also, `p2` will never start as it will be perpetually waiting on `p1` to join

Comment: It does print 'Hello' until the end of time due to your `while 1:` loop.

Comment: No, it doesn't print anything, even the same code without loops.

Comment: Could you add a `print('something')` statement inside `main()` function? Does it print anything?

Comment: Then your problem is probably a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355878/python-multiprocessing-no-output-with-while-loop-in-worker-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `Queue`?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f1(q):
  while 1:
    q.put('Hello')

def f2(q):
  while 1:
    q.put('Goodbye')


def main():
  q = Queue()
  p1 = Process(target=f1, args=(q,))
  p1.start()

  p2 = Process(target=f2, args=(q,))
  p2.start()

  while True:
     try:
        print q.get()
     except:
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should save it and run outside the IDE:

```
C:\> python multi.py
```

then it infinitely prints out `Hello`. You should change your main to see both `Hello` and `Goodbye`:

```
def main():
  p1 = Process(target=f1, args=())
  p2 = Process(target=f2, args=())

  p1.start()
  p2.start()

  p1.join()
  p2.join()
```

Then you have a little happy race condition that constantly prints out `GHoodbyeello` because both processes use the same stdout resource concurrently.